# What is the difference between a curve-based object and a mesh-based object?

Tags: mesh, export, bezier-curves

Is a cylinder that is created using a curve + extrude different from one that is created by mesh? I guess rendering would look the same, but what would be the difference when they are exported to obj files? Is it recommended to convert curves to meshes?